# Displaying data in a table at Widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I've the below code, that fetch data from url, and display it in the Widget, this is a csv data, how can I dislay it as a table?

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:csv/csv.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

Future<List<List<dynamic>>> fetchUserData() async {
  final request = await HttpClient().getUrl(Uri.parse(
      'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQvf9tp4-fETDJbC-HRmRKvVFAXEAGO4lrYPpVeiYkB6nqqXdSs3CjX0eBMvjIoEeX9_qU6K2RWmzVk/pub?gid=0&single=true&output=csv'));
  final response = await request.close();
  List<List<dynamic>> rowsAsListOfValues;
  await for (final csvString in response.transform(const Utf8Decoder())) {
    rowsAsListOfValues =
        const CsvToListConverter().convert(csvString);
  }
 // print(rowsAsListOfValues);
  return rowsAsListOfValues;
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var rowsAsListOfValues;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    rowsAsListOfValues = "Loading data...";
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() async {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    rowsAsListOfValues = await fetchUserData();
    super.setState(() {}); // to update widget data
    print(rowsAsListOfValues);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              '$rowsAsListOfValues',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I know there is [DataTable](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DataTable-class.html) widget, but do not know how to connect it with Dynamic data.

[image]

With static data, the code will be like:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:csv/csv.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(App());
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: HomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _AppState createState() => _AppState();
}

Future<List<List<dynamic>>> fetchUserData() async {
  final request = await HttpClient().getUrl(Uri.parse(
      'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQvf9tp4-fETDJbC-HRmRKvVFAXEAGO4lrYPpVeiYkB6nqqXdSs3CjX0eBMvjIoEeX9_qU6K2RWmzVk/pub?gid=0&single=true&output=csv'));
  final response = await request.close();
  List<List<dynamic>> rowsAsListOfValues;
  await for (final csvString in response.transform(const Utf8Decoder())) {
    rowsAsListOfValues =
        const CsvToListConverter().convert(csvString);
  }
  return rowsAsListOfValues;
}

class _AppState extends State<HomePage> {
  var rowsAsListOfValues;

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() async {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    rowsAsListOfValues = await fetchUserData();
    super.setState(() {}); // to update widget data
    /// new
    print(rowsAsListOfValues);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    rowsAsListOfValues = "Loading data...";
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              '$rowsAsListOfValues',
            ),
            DataTable(
              columns: const <DataColumn>[
                DataColumn(
                  label: Text(
                    'City',
                    style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                  ),
                ),
                DataColumn(
                  label: Text(
                    'Branches',
                    style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
              rows: const <DataRow>[
                DataRow(
                  cells: <DataCell>[
                    DataCell(Text('Dammam')),
                    DataCell(Text('2')),
                  ],
                ),
                DataRow(
                  cells: <DataCell>[
                    DataCell(Text('Khobar')),
                    DataCell(Text('3')),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This document has only one data column: ranches. You have to modify it.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQvf9tp4-fETDJbC-HRmRKvVFAXEAGO4lrYPpVeiYkB6nqqXdSs3CjX0eBMvjIoEeX9_qU6K2RWmzVk/pub?gid=0&single=true&output=csv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `List.generate(rowsAsListOfValues.length - 1` to avoid header
code snippet

```
List<List<dynamic>> rowsAsListOfValues;
...
rowsAsListOfValues == null
                ? CircularProgressIndicator()
                : DataTable(
                    ...
                    rows: List.generate(rowsAsListOfValues.length - 1, (index) {
                      return DataRow(
                        cells: <DataCell>[
                          DataCell(Text('${rowsAsListOfValues[index + 1][0]}')),
                          DataCell(Text('${rowsAsListOfValues[index + 1][1]}')),
                        ],
                      );
                    })),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:csv/csv.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(App());
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: HomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _AppState createState() => _AppState();
}

Future<List<List<dynamic>>> fetchUserData() async {
  final request = await HttpClient().getUrl(Uri.parse(
      'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQvf9tp4-fETDJbC-HRmRKvVFAXEAGO4lrYPpVeiYkB6nqqXdSs3CjX0eBMvjIoEeX9_qU6K2RWmzVk/pub?gid=0&single=true&output=csv'));
  final response = await request.close();
  List<List<dynamic>> rowsAsListOfValues;
  await for (final csvString in response.transform(const Utf8Decoder())) {
    rowsAsListOfValues = const CsvToListConverter().convert(csvString);
  }
  return rowsAsListOfValues;
}

class _AppState extends State<HomePage> {
  List<List<dynamic>> rowsAsListOfValues;

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() async {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    rowsAsListOfValues = await fetchUserData();
    super.setState(() {}); // to update widget data
    /// new
    print(rowsAsListOfValues);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            rowsAsListOfValues == null
                ? Text("Loading data...")
                : Text(
                    '$rowsAsListOfValues',
                  ),
            rowsAsListOfValues == null
                ? CircularProgressIndicator()
                : DataTable(
                    columns: const <DataColumn>[
                        DataColumn(
                          label: Text(
                            'City',
                            style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                          ),
                        ),
                        DataColumn(
                          label: Text(
                            'Branches',
                            style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    rows: List.generate(rowsAsListOfValues.length - 1, (index) {
                      return DataRow(
                        cells: <DataCell>[
                          DataCell(Text('${rowsAsListOfValues[index + 1][0]}')),
                          DataCell(Text('${rowsAsListOfValues[index + 1][1]}')),
                        ],
                      );
                    })),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for showing the `CircularProgressIndicator()` as a bonus point in the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Table` widget like this:

```
  List<List<dynamic>> rowsAsListOfValues;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(      
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Table(
          columnWidths: {
            0: FixedColumnWidth(100.0),
            1: FixedColumnWidth(200.0),
          },
          border: TableBorder.all(width: 1.0),
          children: rowsAsListOfValues.map((item) {
            return TableRow(
                children: item.map((row) {
                  return Container(
                   
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Text(
                        row.toString(),
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }).toList());
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```